# Force jQuery-autocomplete (From Array, Modified version) to show the suggestions even if nothing is typed

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, usability

I have this version of jQuery-autocomplete: [jQuery Autocomplete Mod](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm), It's cool with me till the moment But I'd like to get slight customization of it:

**I want `onclick` a list appears holding all of the possible suggestions! even if there is nothing in the input box**

Somethings you should know:

- I have a problem with the 'Traditional' Html ComboBox since I have to customize it with pictures and something like that.
- I'm not using it with AJAX instead from a pre defined Array 
  `$('#inputbox').autocompleteArray();`
- I want to use it like `Dropdown list with auto complete` more than `Ajax autocomplete`. So any better suggestion is welcomed `:")`
- I love jQuery and feel like stick with it so **any plug-in for it is preferred :D.**

I feel here like a spoiled programmer so if any suggesting on these it would be appreciated:

- it's good to show the whole list on click even if theres is anything typed.
- showing the whole list if the input is not in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jQuery.SexyCombo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/SexyCombo) is the answer.

Comment: @bgreen1989 but be careful with it, since you might be required to add extra features or design. In this case sexy combo is no longer the answer. In fact I don't use it anymore, and this answer is very old. I use my own favor (yes I hacked the whole module) of this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox, it's kind of official and works within the jQuery coding standards, you can go wild with it doing any possible customizations that your skills can get you.